# PHP/mysql, Using foreign keys to insert(id) by accepting (name) from form

Tags: php

I have 2 tables, one called **school** and one called **student**. Inside **student** I have several columns, one being a foreign key of **school_Id**. I also have several columns in **school** table(i.e. school_Id, name,...). I accept '**name**' of the **school** from form. i want to insert the '**school_Id**' in **student** table.

To select '**school_Id**' I use....(*$schno - is the accepted 'name' from form)

```
$sno="SELECT  school_Id FROM school where Name='$schno' ";

$resno = mysql_query($sno) or die("query error".mysql_error());
```

To insert the value to **student** table I use:

```
$sql="insert into  student values('$no','$fname','$mname','$lname','$bdate','$age','$sex','$batch','$year','$manam','$mafnam','$resno')";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die("query error".mysql_error());

                    ..but it isn't working.
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: In the first block of code, you just run the query but did NOT fetch the result! See [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

Comment: please describe the question you want to ask in a simpler way... may be adding the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must fetch the data after you run mysql_query function:

   $sql="SELECT  school_Id FROM school where Name='$schno' ";

   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("query error".mysql_error());

   $resno = mysql_fetch_field($result, 0);
2. If it's an integer, don't use quotes in INSERT query: : `'$resno'` -> `,$resno`.
3. Please, quote your variables with mysql_​real_​escape_​string before using them in query.
4. Consider switching to PDO or mysqli as mysql lib is deprecated.